# Is there any command to get app package build version number for iOS using terminal?

Tags: ios, mobile, automation, appium, ios-ui-automation

Is there any command to get app package build version number for iOS using terminal ?

In Android I can get the build version using adb command want to know similar way to get build version number for iOS.

**For Android**

> adb shell dumpsys package package_name | grep versionName

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no straightforward way to achieve this similar to `adb shell` but there are two ways I can suggest you try out:

1. If the app is already installed on the device using [go-ios](https://github.com/danielpaulus/go-ios):

- Download the binary for your OS
- Execute `./ios apps --udid=YOUR-DEVICE-UDID`
- You will get output in JSON which you can parse, find the object for your app by `bundleIdentifier` and inside that JSON object you can find `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion`

2. If you have the IPA file using fastlane [get_ipa_info_plist_value](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/get_ipa_info_plist_value/)

- Install fastlane
- Execute `fastlane run get_ipa_info_plist_value`
- Provide the path to your IPA file when asked
- Provide the key value you want to get from Info.plist: either `CFBundleShortVersionString` or `CFBundleVersion`